# Fast MySQL query on local environment but slow on server

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, mamp

Locally I have MAMP installed and if I try to use MySQL select query then it takes about 2ms but the same query on server's MySQL takes about 40ms. Both MySQL environments have same version 5.7.24. Both tables that I'm using are identical - same columns, same indexes, same table type (InnoDB).

What would be the problem? If I have to work with 100k rows then there is huge difference in time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell the difference without knowing much more about your database,
query and setup, but you can find it out yourself with profiling:

```
SET profiling = 1;
SELECT /*your query*/
SHOW PROFILES;            /*see the id for this query, probably 1*/
SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1
```

You may also use the
[EXPLAIN command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html)
for analyzing aspects such as buffering results for sorting and others.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Here are results:
starting 0.000132
checking permissions 0.000015
Opening tables 0.000040
init 0.000057
System lock 0.000017
optimizing 0.000007
statistics 0.000021
preparing 0.000021
executing 0.000006
Sending data 0.004991
end 0.009383
query end 0.000045
closing tables 0.000022
freeing items 0.000424
cleaning up 0.000034

Comment: Sending data followed by "end" is the major part, which incorporates query execution and sending the result. The difference might be related to normal network overhead and the size of the result. It would certainly be very slow to send a result set of 100k rows over the network.